# Meaning of "as" in the sentence, "I am confused, as is my dentist"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "as" in the following sentence,

> I have a cavity in almost every tooth. I am confused, as is my dentist.

Does "I am confused, as is my dentist" mean " I am confused, confused is my dentist (my dentist is confused)" ?

Can "as" refer to an adjective, "confused"?

What is the difference in the meaning between "I am confused, as is my dentist"  and "I am confused, so is my dentist"?

Comment: **as is** there indicates existential similarity. I am in a state of confusion.  My dentist is in a state of confusion. Both patient and dentist are confused. There is no difference in meaning between **as** and **so** there. *I live on Mars. So does he.   I live on Mars, as does he.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: But there are *syntactic* differences. Orthographically, as illustrated by your own examples, most of us would incorporate the ***as-** clause* into the existing sentence by using a comma, but with ***so*** we'd normally make it a separate sentence. Also, although it's slightly "marked", it's not impossible to "front" the ***as-** clause* - for example, *As does the Queen, I avoid farting in public*. You can't do that with the ***so*** version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: agreed, as my punctuation indicates. But the OP didn't ask about syntactic differences :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I know that, as do you. When I started typing my comment my only concern was to call OP's attention to that punctuation difference, since it might otherwise have passed unnoticed. When the possibility of "fronting" occurred to me I thought it was at least worth flagging that up for OP and possible future visitors. But I must admit that even though I can't offhand think of a context where there could be a *semantic* distinction, I wouldn't feel confident asserting that no such examples could exist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But note that I wrote "There is no difference in meaning between **so** and **as** *there*." [emphasis added]

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: As is often the case, you seem preoccupied with defending yourself against supposed detractions that were never intended. If OP is sufficiently on the ball to both notice *and* understand the significance of your precise phrasing, he'd hardly need to be posting questions here! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm replying to your comment "I wouldn't feel confident asserting that no such examples could exist", which one could take to be either  (a) a non-sequitur  or (b) a criticism that I had done just that.   Giving you the benefit of the doubt, I chose (b).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I long ago gave up trying to gain the upper hand in comment exchanges with you. But I'll just say that you missed the third possible reason (the one actually *intended*, as it happens) for my "I wouldn't feel confident asserting that no such examples could exist". I was simply obliquely inviting you to contribute such an example, if you could think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this usage "as" works to show *equivalence* between two things.  It says "in the same way that A is something, B is also the same thing"

> I am a redhead, as was my father, and his father before him.
>
> Bill became a pilot at 16 years old, as did Mary.

As Tᴚoɯɐuo and FumbleFingers mention in the comments, there is little difference in *meaning* between "as" and "so" in this case.  They're two ways to say the same thing.  However there is a difference in use since with "so" you start a new sentence, either with a period or a semicolon.

> I am a redhead. So is my father.
>
> We're going to the movies; so are our parents.

Because of the difference in punctuation, the use of "as" can *feel* like the two elements of the sentence are more connected because one *flows* smoothly into the other.  But this is a subtle distinction that relates more to the punctuation than the grammar structures.